# Insert HTML tag and remove comma from php variable

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have PHP variable like:

```
$biling_cycles = 'Monthly,Annually';
```

I want it to be:

```
$biling_cycles = '<span> Monthly, </span> <span> Annually </span>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code Below Works for me:

```
<?php
 $biling_cycles = 'Monthly, Annually';
 $cycles = explode(', ', $biling_cycles);
 foreach($cycles as $cycle):
  echo '<span>';
  echo $cycle;
  echo "</span>";
 endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
$billing_cycles = 'Monthly, Annually';
$temp = '';
foreach (explode(', ', $billing_cycles) as $key => $value) {
    $temp .= "<span> $value </span>,";
}
$biling_cycles = rtrim($temp, ','); // removes trainling comma

echo $billing_cycles;
```

Result is: `<span> Monthly </span>,<span> Annually </span>`

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these simple steps:**

```
$biling_cycles = 'Monthly, Annually';
$cycles = explode(', ', $biling_cycles);
$span_added = "";
foreach($cycles as $cycle){
$span_added = $span_added+"<span>"+$cycle+"</span>, ";
}
echo $span_added;
```

**Output:**

```
<span> Monthly </span>,<span> Annually </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to explode and iterate.

Just replace all commas with a comma, space, closing tag, space, opening tag, space.  Then wrap the whole thing in an openong and closing tag.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bblIl))

```
$billing_cycles = 'Monthly,Annually';

echo '<span> '
     . str_replace(',', ', </span> <span> ', $billing_cycles)
     . ' </span>';
```